# How to setup trap in bash functions?

Tags: bash, trap

I can setup `trap` in bash scripts but not bash functions.

For example, `source` the code below and run `f`, now try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it's not been trapped!

How to setup `trap` in bash functions?

```
  4 trap ctrl_c INT
  5 
  6 ctrl_c () {
  7  echo "** Trapped CTRL-C"
  8 }
  9 
 10 
 11 f () {
 12   for i in `seq 1 100`; do
 13     sleep 1
 14     echo -n "."
 15   done
 16 }
```

Comment: You may put an `f` at the end of your code, and removing the space from the `f ()`.

Answer (score 8):

That's because it sends SIGINT to the process in the foreground instead of to `bash` (which is running the script). If you want to do this, make the function asynchronous and then use `wait` (which will act as expected and use the trap).

Comment: It kind of works. But I found that if `f` is in a pipe `echo 123 | f`, then it's not trapping?

Comment: @Cheng Use a subshell (and a pipe in this case is unnecessary anyway, just use a heredoc/herestring). `(command | command) &`

Answer (score 1):

Protip: Send the foreground process a QUIT with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, -<kbd>Z</kbd>, -<kbd>D</kbd> aren't working.

Clear traps at the end of execution with `trap - list of signals here`

Fun on a non-production system: Try setting a trap for all sensible signals (e.g., not KILL).  `kill -l` (not that's a lower-case L not a number 1 or pipe |)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make the function global

```
#!/bin/bash
trap ctrl_c INT
ctrl_c () {
  echo "** Trapped CTRL-C"
} 
for i in `seq 1 100`; do
  sleep 1
  echo -n "."
done
```

Comment: `INT` and `SIGINT` are synonymous -- it will make no difference.